# Find elements in a specific area of svg using only getBoundingClientRect

Tags: javascript, python, svg

I'm creating an `SVG` file using `python svgwrite` and there's a shape in the center of my drawing that I created with a path. I want to remove elements that are not inside my wrapper shape.

first of all, can I remove them in the `svgwrite`? if not how can I find all the elements in the frontend using javascript to remove any of them that are not inside my shape?

#### svgwrite

```py
# dots that are genrated in the svg are like this
image.add(image.circle((x, y), mag, id='dot', stroke="none", fill=color))

# this is my heart shape that should dots go inside of it
image.defs.add(image.path(d="M0 200 v-200 h200 a100,100 90 0,1 0,200 a100,100 90 0,1 -200,0z", id="heart_shape", style="rotate: 225deg;scale:1.9;stroke: #fff;", opacity="1"))
image.add(image.use(href="#heart_shape", fill="none", insert=(half_x, str(height-80)+"mm"), id="heart_wrapper"))
```

I prefer to delete them in the frontend using javascript. I got the bounding of my shape like below:

```js
var heart = document.querySelector("#heart_wrapper")
var {xHeart, yHeart} = heart.getBBox()
```

###### Note: The thing I do not know exactly is that how to determine if a `dot` is inside my shape. I know how to select all of the dots and just remove them

Here is the generated svg shape:

```html
<use xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" fill="none" id="heart_wrapper" x="377.9527559055118" xlink:href="#heart_shape" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" y="195mm">
<path d="M0 200 v-200 h200 a100,100 90 0,1 0,200 a100,100 90 0,1 -200,0z" id="heart_shape" opacity="1" style="rotate: 225deg;scale:1.9;stroke: #fff;"></path>
</use>
```

Comment: BTW I find that The element.getBoundingClientRect() method will return the proper coordinates of an element relative to the viewport regardless of whether the SVG has been scaled and/or translated. so getBBox() is the method I should use

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have the elements for `svg`, the `heart` and the `dot`, you can use `checkIntersection` to check if an element is present within the boundary of another. So, to check if `dot` is inside the `heart`:

```
var intersecting = svg.checkIntersection(dot, heart.getBBox());
```